# how can a define that a function is neither even nor odd without using negation words or symbols?

Tags: calculus, definition

I understand all the definitons

If $f(-x) = f(x)$, the function is even.

If $f(-x) = - f(x)$, the function is odd.

If $f(-x) \neq f(x)$ and $f(-x) \neq -f(x)$, the function is neither even nor odd.

now i dont know how to define that a function is neither even nor odd without using negation words or symbols

thanks for the help

Comment: Seem like artificial constraints.  How about "a function $f$ is neither even nor odd iff there exist $x_1,x_2$ such that $f(-x_1)\neq f(x_1)$ and $f(-x_2)\neq -f(x_2)$"  ?

Comment: exellent , already wrote that, how i can do this without using negation words or symbols

Comment: I don't see where you wrote that.  And I don't see any way to avoid "negations" or "symbols".  As I said, those seem like artificial constraints.  Can you provide a complete list of all the "symbols" we are forbidden from using?

Comment: I've seen lots of strange restrictions on this site, but "without using negation words or symbols" beats them all.

Answer (score 2):

If you're allowed to use the "$>$" symbol then you could simulate inequality in the definition: $x \ne 0$ if and only if $x^2 > 0$.  So, $f$ is neither even nor odd could be expressed as:
$$ \left[\exists x \in \mathbb{R}, (f(x) - f(-x))^2 > 0 \right] \wedge \left[\exists y \in \mathbb{R}, (f(y) + f(-y))^2 > 0 \right]. $$

(However, as the other commenters have indicated, this is still somewhat artificial.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an even function, it should be symmetric about the y-axis. If you fold your graph across the y axis, both halves of the function should line up with each other.

If you have an odd function, you have to first flip the left half of the graph and then it will be symmetric when you reflect on the y axis.

That, or you can visualize rotating the entire right half of an odd function's graph by 180 degrees, and it should line up with the left half.

Comment: hi , it didnt answer the question...

Comment: It seems that Jsevillamol gave a good answer: if a function does not have any of the above symmetries, it's neither even nor odd. I'm not sure what you're looking for: you're almost asking "describe everything that isn't a grey elephant without using negation words or symbols"...

Comment: for sure, but the question is how i can define a function that is even nor odd without using negation words or symbols...

Comment: An even function is something that is its reflection about the y axis. An odd function is a function that is unchanged when you rotate it 180 degrees counterclockwise. And I'm not sure you can define a neither even nor odd functions without negations or symbols, because to give a good intuition on how to make a function not-even and not-odd, I need to have an example of such a function (like $x^2$)...

Comment: i have also the intuition.. already understand all the topic. the thing is that i need to define it without using negation symbols and im stuck..

Answer (score 0):

Even functions have a simmetry along the $x=0$ axis.

Odd functions have a simmetry along the $x=-y$ axis.

Functions that do not have either of this simmetries are neither even nor odd.

One example of such a function is $f(x)=x^2+x+1$ ([plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+%2B+x+%2B+1)).

Comment: hi , it didnt answer the question...

Answer (score 0):

if there exists a point x1 ∈ D such that f (−x1) is undefined